# Always getting No file exists

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a file with Python and Tkinter, this is what I have:

```
file1 = ""
file2 = ""

file1entry = Entry().pack()
file2entry = Entry().pack()

def OpenFile1():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/",
                           filetypes=(("Text File", "*.txt"),
                                      ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    # Using try in case user types in unknown file or closes without choosing a file.
    try:
        with open(name, 'r') as UseFile:
            file1 = UseFile
            file1entry.text = file1
    except:
        print("No file exists")
```

No matter what I tried, when choosing a file, I always get `No file exists`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ensured that the file exists in your working directory?

Comment: @blackbrandt yes, it is, but isn't the file dialog should let me choose file from everywhere?

Comment: Don't use a bald `except`.  Catch an exception and print its error message.

Comment: eg: `except Exception as e: print("error: ", e, file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. I don't really know what to do, I just need to write this simple python gui to choose the file, I don't work in Python usually.

Comment: What is `Entry`?  Does the `pack` method of the object it returns usually produce an object with a `text` attribute?

Comment: It looks like Entry().pack() is returning None

Comment: @WilliamPursell I deleted Entry, I try to just open the file after the user choose and read it's text. but I just get name 'file1' is not defined, altough it is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

file1entry does not exist in the scope of the function, so when you try to define its `.text` attribute you receive an error.

Python requires you to explicitly state whether a variable is global.

If you place the line

```py
global file1entry
```

at the top of the function, it should work.

This would make the new code:

```py
file1 = ""
file2 = ""

file1entry = Entry().pack()
file2entry = Entry().pack()

def OpenFile1():
    global file1entry 
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/",
                           filetypes=(("Text File", "*.txt"),
                                      ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    # Using try in case user types in unknown file or closes without choosing a file.
    try:
        with open(name, 'r') as UseFile:
            file1 = UseFile
            file1entry.text = file1
    except:
        print("No file exists")
```

Comment: `file1entry` is still None, and it wouldn't be an object that you can usefully assign something to its `.text` attribute even if it wasn't None.